# Remote monitoring Azure Products

Tags: azure, monitoring

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to monitor Azure products (HDInsight, SQL Storage, etc) via API (or SDK or CLI), but from the documentation I can't figure it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is this even possible? Is there some documentation or tutorial somewhere that can help me understand how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out .NET nuget packages for Azure Management, specifically Azure Monitoring http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring/

Here's an example on how to talk to this library:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/02/20/how-to-use-windows-azure-monitoring-services-management-library-to-create-an-autoscale-rule.aspx
(although for auto-scaling rules, not monitoring, but connection is similar).

If you want to be more hands-off and white-glove about monitoring for Azure, check out http://cloudmonix.com
Disclaimer: affiliated with CloudMonix